# explode/implode array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, explode, implode

Not sure why I am having this problem.  I have used this same code on a previous project with no problems.

I'm generating an array using checkboxes in JavaScript.  I can successfully $.post the array to PHP, but I keep receiving the following error:

> **Warning**:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array
>   given in **D:\htdocs\deliverynoticeV2\process\updateRecord.php** on
>   line **14**
>
> **Warning**:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
>   **D:\htdocs\deliverynoticeV2\process\updateRecord.php** on line
>   **15**

It repeats the same error about 4 times, as I have 4 different arrays I'm sending over.

Starting with the JavaScript:

```
$('#updateRecords').on('click', function(e)
{ 
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#updateForm input').val('');

  var checkcontainer = [];
  var checkorder = [];
  var checktrucker = [];
  var checkconsignee = [];

  $(".checkEdit:checked").each(function(){
    checkcontainer.push($(this).data("checkcontainer"));
    checkorder.push($(this).data("checkorder"));
    checktrucker.push($(this).data("checktrucker")); 
    checkconsignee.push($(this).data("checkconsignee")); 
  });

  console.log(checkcontainer);

  $.post('process/updateRecord.php', {checkcontainer:checkcontainer,
  checkorder:checkorder, checktrucker:checktrucker, checkconsignee:checkconsignee}, 
  function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
  }); 
});
```

When I console out the variable 'checkcontainer', I see the following:

```
["FSCU7122545", "TGHU6235458", "TCNU6900047"]
```

Over in PHP, the code looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['checkcontainer']))
{
  $checkcontainer = $_POST['checkcontainer'];
  $checkorder = $_POST['checkorder'];
  $checktrucker = $_POST['checktrucker'];
  $checkconsignee = $_POST['checkconsignee'];

  $containerSplit = explode(",", $checkcontainer);
  $containers = "'" . implode("', '", $containerSplit) . "'";
  $orderSplit = explode(",", $checkorder);
  $orders = "'" . implode("', '", $orderSplit) . "'";
  $truckerSplit = explode(",", $checktrucker);
  $truckers = "'" . implode("', '", $truckerSplit) . "'";      
  $consigneeSplit = explode(",", $checkconsignee);
  $consignees = "'" . implode("', '", $consigneeSplit) . "'";

  echo $containers;
}
?>
```

As stated, I've used this same code in a previous project.  Why am I receiving the above error?

Comment: Explode is used on a string to make an array not on an array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need the `explode()` calls before your `implode()` ones because the data you send are arrays (Your variables in your js are arrays).
So all your `$_POST` variables are arrays.

Comment: Success.  I wonder why I didn't have this problem in my previous project.  I may have to revisit just to see why.  Thank you for your quick resolution.

Comment: You might have been sending your data differently

Comment: Thanks again, my friend.  I will accept your answer when the system permits me to.